# GELF logging appender using TLS

Tags: java, encryption, tcp, tls1.2, graylog

I am using the GraylogAppender from my java webapp (log4j1) to send logging over TCP to my graylog server.

In the graylog (graylog2) server I have a TCP input which supports TLS, using a tls certificate file.

I would like to enable encryption and client identification for my logging.

Anyone know how to create the certificate file, and use it in the java webapp client with the GraylogAppender?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of GELF appenders for Log4j 1.x on the [Graylog Marketplace](https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons?search=log4j).

Personally, I'd recommend using [logstash-gelf](https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons/7ea104bd-519d-4140-a396-ff962314415e).

Comment: Do you know how to use TLS with this (or any other) GELF appender?

Comment: There's an open feature request for TLS support in logstash-gelf: https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf/issues/95

But yeah, you're correct. None of these log4j 1.x appenders seems to support TLS out of the box.

FWIW, this log4j 2.x appender does: https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons/dc8bf2fb-fbce-4e60-8737-ba71c30bcea9

Comment: FYI, logstash-gelf now supports TLS: https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf/releases/tag/logstash-gelf-1.11.0